# How to do ajax enable

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

i want to do my visual studio 2008 (2.0) ajax enable...please suggest me what i will have to what tool kit or dll i will have to include and how will i configure it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are step by step instructions on [how to setup the Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act.ashx).
If you are specifically using .NET 2.0 framework, you will need to use the older release of the toolkit which you can find [here](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/11121).

Once you have it set up in Visual Studio, you will also need to put a copy of the AjaxControlToolkit.dll into the /bin folder of your website.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to look at [ASP.NET AJAX ToolKit](http://www.asp.net/%28S%28wnmvzu45umnszm455c1qs522%29%29/ajax/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/)